# QChartView, RubberBand and right mouse button behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I have class, derived from `QChartView`, and I have enabled rubber band selection in it

```
MyChartView::MyChartView(QChart* chart)
:QChartView(chart)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
    setInteractive(true);
    setRubberBand(RectangleRubberBand);
}
```

Qt documentation says that

> If left mouse button is released and the rubber band is enabled then event is accepted and the view is zoomed into the rect specified by the rubber band. If it is a right mouse button event then the view is zoomed out.

I don't want to have right button zoom out. I tried to override `mouseReleaseEvent`

```
void MyChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->buttons() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        std::cout << "my overriden event" << std::endl;
        return; //event doesn't go further
    }
    QChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(e);//any other event
}
```

but it does not print anything.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solution is very simple. I have just mixed `button()` and `buttons()` functions. The following code works properly:

```
void MyChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        std::cout << "my overriden event" << std::endl;
        return; //event doesn't go further
    }
    QChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(e);//any other event
}
```

Comment: this is helping but it could potentially impair the use of the Righ button for other purposes like opening contextual menu.
Looking at Qt5 source code of chartview, on can see that the state of the rubberband is checked and the event is eventually passed to GraphicView::mouseReleaseEvent.
So one could directly pass the event to GraphicsView in case of RightButton.

Answer (score 1):

here is my working solution for Qt5 :

```
void MyChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }
    else
    {
        QChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }
}
```

It has the advantage to allow a contextual menu to be opened with the right click.